# Best resource for concentration of measure?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, reference-request, concentration-of-measure

What are the best resources to learn concentration of measure phenomenon and concentration inequalities? I have heard that Talagrand's papers are good, but they are not particularly good read.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the material mentioned by air,

- [Concentration of Measure Inequalities in Information Theory, Communications and Coding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4663)
- [Lecture notes by Lugosi](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/anu.pdf)  (Essentially superceeded by Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence by Boucheron, Lugosi and Massart, but freely available online)
- Concentration of Measure for the Analysis of Randomized Algorithms by Dubhashi ,Panconesi
- Terry Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/)
- Lecture notes on machine learning (e.g. this set by [Wasserman](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/))

Comment: Ahhh nice, totally forgot about Larry's course: Coupled with the videos this might really be the easiest way to get an initial sense of what concentration inequalities are!

Comment: The applications are also just Math.  What could be a bridge between the math and actual implementation code  ?Is it up to me to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Two very accessible resources on concentration inequalities are the following:

- Ramon van Handel's lecture notes on ["Probability in high dimension"](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ervan/APC550.pdf)
- The book [Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019876765X) by Boucheron, Lugosi and Massart.

Answer (score 1):

In Marseille, France, Sudeep Kamath delivered an excellent four-part video lecture on concentration of measure, and writes mathematical proofs for entropic and transport-related concentration inequalities:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Sudeep+Kamath+%3A+Concentration+of+Measure

1. Variance bounds
2. Information inequalities
3. Entropy method
4. Transportation method

Based on this outline alone, his lectures seem to resemble the table of contents of:

- *Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence* by  Stéphane Boucheron, Gábor Lugosi, and Pascal Massart, 2013.

For those interested, the **transportation-information inequalities** that appear in concentration of measure can be [discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899126/transportation-information-inequalities/).

Answer (score 0):

I like Roman Vershynin's book [High Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)